# How to get a Custom Validation Attribute to return different localized error messages depending on the situation?

Tags: c#

I have a custom validation attribute for parsing dates and I want to return a different error message based on the different ways for a user to mess up the date. I have properties which I can set when creating the attribute that allow me to differentiate the error messages but I can't seem to pass in localized strings for them.

Here's the code:

```
public sealed class CustomAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string InvalidDateFormat { get; set; }
    public string InvalidDateFormatFuture { get; set; }
    public string InvalidDateFormatPast { get; set; }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // [...] 

        if (date is invalid)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(InvalidDateFormat);
        }

        if (parsed date is too old)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(InvalidDateFormatPast);
        }

        if (if date is in the future)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(InvalidDateFormatFuture);
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

And here's how I'm using the attribute:

```
[DateValidation(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Language), InvalidDateFormat = nameof(Language.InvalidDateFormat, InvalidDateFormatPast = nameof(Language.InvalidDateFormatPast), InvalidDateFormatFuture = nameof(Language.InvalidDateFormatFuture))]
public string Date { get; set; }
```

But when trying this out, I get just get the messages "InvalidDateFormat", "InvalidDateFormatPast", "InvalidDateFormatFuture"

Removing the nameof(X) gives me the following error:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array create expression of an attribute parameter type

Comment: Can you use "Language" inside your custom attribute?

Comment: @Progman I cannot unfortunately

Comment: What about using static properties which you initialize on application start?

Comment: That would work... but seems inefficient? I'd have to create static properties for every message I'd need which could be a lot

Comment: What about moving the "Language" resources to a new assembly and reference this new assembly as a dependency wherever you need the "Language" resource? This would remove the need to use assembly references to access the "Language" resource which doesn't make sense or would result in cycle references.